# Alternative to content-based routing for separating tasks across regions in the world

Tags: nservicebus, masstransit, rebus

As we all know, content-based routing is frowned upon. The routing should be done using the message type. But how would you solve a situation in which the servers listening to a queue are spread in the EU & USA regions, and we want to deliver those messages to the appropriate region.

It seems like a classic scenario for content-based routing: by adding a "region field (like in the widget/gadget example at Enterprise Integration Pattern book)

Thanks

------------ Edit 31/10/15 ----------------

in reply to @mookid, with regards to rebus solution proposition:

Up until recently I had the notion that commands are bad ("ruins the architecture|) because I assumed that sending to an endpoint meant a specific consumer (by ip address). So I preferred using events for everything, which then caused the trouble of how to solve the regions problem.

But now that I think about it, I can use IOrderPlaced interface, and create 2 endpoints for each message: IOrderPlaced_USA, IORderPlaced_EU.
the name of the endpoint will be put in app.config, and so the USA servers will have a different app.config than the EU servers.

this will allow me to use the same RabbitMQ server for both regions, but won't allow me to send a message from EU to USA - this might be acceptable
is my understanding above correct?

I'm having trouble putting all the pieces together, could you provide your view about how is your proposed solution compares?

Thanks

Comment: And where are the machines that are sending the messages?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood but I will say this:
we have servers in the EU, and other servers in the US. we'll have a Coordinator (who will handle the sagas) which will be in one of those regions (not decided yet)

Comment: You are making a few statements and assumptions, about the fact that region specific messages should be delivered to the appropriate region and the fact that commands are bad. The latter isn't true by default, but maybe in specific scenarios another option could be better. This isn't a black & white fact. I use commands a lot, but the same goes for events.

More importantly, why would you want region specific messages? What's the functional / logical reasoning behind this?

Comment: "**up until recently** I had the notion that commands are bad". With regards to region: I need region specific messages because the tasks they are performing is moving data around (to/where in the arguments of the message) so I wouldn't want a server in EU moving data between servers in the US

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the coordinator and why it would be in just one region.

Comment: We would prefer not having a coordinator (=saga handler) per region as this would increase the overhead required (preferabbly we'll have 2 clustered coordinators for reliability, but that doesn't necessarly has to be one per region)

Answer (score 0):

When you say that "routing should be done using the message type", that's just the main routing strategy that NServiceBus and the other .NET service buses happen to encourage you to use.

This strategy works well in many scenarios, but there's just as many scenarios where it can be nice to do what you're requesting.

Since you tagged the question with both NServiceBus and MassTransit, I assume you haven't decided on a messaging library yet - so I took the liberty of adding the Rebus tag, and then I can show you how you can do content-based routing with Rebus.

Let's assume you want to send a `DoSomething` message, and you want it routed to two different queues depending on some field in the message. One way of achieving this, would be to

```
await bus.SendLocal(new DoSomething { Region = "US" });
```

which sends the message to the bus' own input queue, and then you have a handler that looks like this:

```
public class DoSomethingForwarder : IHandleMessages<DoSomething>
{
    readonly IBus bus;

    public DoSomethingForwarder(IBus bus)
    {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public async Task Handle(DoSomething message)
    {
        var destination = DecideWhereToSend(message);

        await bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.Forward(destination);
    }

    string DecideWhereToSend(DoSomething message)
    {
        //I'll leave the implementation to you :)
    }
}
```

using the advanced API for routing the raw transport message to another destination.

If you want to make your router faster and more robuts towards message schema changes, you can also route messages based on header values by [adding a "transport message forwarder" via the routing configuration API](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus.Tests/Routing/TestHeaderBasedRouting.cs#L71-L87).

Not sure how NServiceBus and MassTransit do these things, but I'm sure they can do it pretty much the same way.

Comment: thank you @mookid8000, it's nice to know I ain't asking for the unreasonable, and btw - good catch with regards to your idea about MT/NSB :)

I updated the question with extra details that I'd very much like to hear your view on it